# Angular render component based on device width

Tags: javascript, angular

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the appropriate view / component based on the device width. I have attached an event listener and created an if statement to render the appropriate `ng-template` based on a boolean class flag `mobile`, however when I drag my browser the template doesn't change but the resize event does fire...

**html**

```html
<div class="row dashboard-list-view">
  <div class="col-12" *ngIf="mobile; then mobileListBlock else desktopListBlock"></div>
  <ng-template #desktopListBlock>
    <app-dashboard-list-desktop [data]="data" [filters]="filters"></app-dashboard-list-desktop>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #mobileListBlock>
    <app-dashboard-list-mobile [data]="data" [filters]="filters"></app-dashboard-list-mobile>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeService } from '../../services/resize.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-list',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-list.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any = [];
  @Input() filters: any = [];
  
  mobile: boolean = false;

  constructor(private resizeService: ResizeService){}

  objectKeys = Object.keys;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.resizeService.onResize$.subscribe(this.onWindowResize);
    this.onWindowResize();

  }

  onWindowResize() {

    console.log("Resize!")

    if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
      this.mobile = true;
    } else {
      this.mobile = false;
    }

  }

}
```

I've looked for similar questions but I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong here, thank you in advance!

**Update**

However when I initialize the app on a mobile device it does render the mobile view. Same thing for desktop too. It's just that the event doesn't have any effect  after the initial render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem was this line:

`this.resizeService.onResize$.subscribe(this.onWindowResize);`

changing it to:

`this.resizeService.onResize$.subscribe(() => this.onWindowResize());`

did the trick. It prolly had to do with the `this` context on the member function. No idea why no error was thrown tho...